# Are there any clones of odata.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Are there any clones of odata.stackexchange.com? I would love to give my clients access to their data in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real thing [is open source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54450/stackexchange-data-explorer-is-going-open-source) and can be downloaded [from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/).