# How does StackExchange DataExplorer prevent DOS attacks?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, security

I have seen [the page for composing Data Explorer queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). If I enter some stupid queries like:

```
select * from Posts a, Posts b,  Posts c ..... where 1=1
```

etc., how does StackExchange prevent it from running? I have seen that limit is used. But will that be good enough?

When I did a two join, Chrome crashed after some time as the query took a long time as the loop call goes on...

Comment: +1 Though I think the question should (also) be "How does DataExplorer protect against stupid SQL queries?" (like I've done myself, sadly).

Comment: in a way, it can be possibly used for DOS attacks? eg: compose 100 similar queries and save it then trigger the calls

Comment: Yeah definitely - but I think the chance of being brought down by good intentions is higher, since SEDE is isolated from SO/SE and therefore there isn't much to gain from a DOS attack.

Comment: oh yeah, the data is bimonthly archival

Comment: When query takes too much time to execute, it's timeout. For the rest I think it assume everyone has common sense and there's captcha too for anonymous execution.

Comment: Also, it limits results to 50000.

Comment: You can find out for yourself considering that the [source code is available for the Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54450/stackexchange-data-explorer-is-going-open-source).

Comment: cool! i didn't know about the source and will look into it

Comment: cool cool http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/QueryRunner.cs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the data explorer secured?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107344/how-is-the-data-explorer-secured)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well there are a bunch of things we do

#### The SQL Server instance is isolated and runs on a machine dedicated to data.se, only containing data.se public data.

This means that if stuff goes horribly wrong, performance of the main sites will not be affected.

#### Anonymous have to fill captchas

We had an instance where somebody had the **very bright** idea of running the same query over and over using some **sophisticated robot** like a shell script with wget. This is not going to happen anymore.

#### Throttles throttles and more throttles

There is a limit to the number of queries we will execute per user, per hour

#### Everything is cached

Second time we see any query, the results will be cached, which helps cut down on db traffic

#### Queries time out after 120 seconds

If you mess up and run an expensive query it will timeout. As an exercise for the reader I am not against also throttling CPU time on a per-user basis. Have not had the need to do this yet.

#### Number of results we return is capped

We do not return "infinite" results to the browsers we cap them.